# Deep space acceleration limits?

Tags: physics, space, space-travel

Assuming the power source for such acceleration places no limit on things, how quickly can a space craft be accelerated to the speed necessary to cross the distance between Jupiter and the sun in about 30 days time, without the G forces causing harm or unbearable discomfort to the crew?

Comment: I don't get your question. The clause you pose on non causing harm is the answer you are looking for.

Comment: [This question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/840/how-fast-will-1g-get-you-there) on space.SE talks about a constant 1g acceleration and how long it will take you to get various places.

Comment: @Cadence - Make this an answer and I will accept it after the obligatory 24 hour wait. This is exactly what I needed but couldn't seem to find. Thank you!

Comment: use 9.8m/sec2 as your acceleration and determine it that way. this is a quick plug and chug math problem.

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

•your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers

Comment: I'd suggest you learn basic Newtonian laws of motion (and maybe some basics about orbits) to get a better feel for this.  There are a lot of ways to learn this (YouTube videos, google searches, books) and it's quite useful if you're interested in these kind of questions.

Comment: This is a very simple question asking about a very complex problem.  Half the trip is accelerating, the other half is decelerating.  You can't fly in a straight line because the planets don't politely sit still while you're traveling.  That means a spiral-ish shaped path that could be very long.  It took the [Galileo space craft 6 years](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/137/sixty-five-amazing-galileo-facts/) to get there.  Granted, it didn't have the privilege of constant thrust - but it didn't need to make humans comfortable, either. (\*continued\*)

Comment: I'd recommend changing this question into a [tag:reality-check] question.  Propose (a) the availability of constant thrust (fuel isn't an issue) and (b) the need to travel in 30 days.  Can humans make the trip safely and comfortably?  That might get better results.

Comment: I think you're asking about accelerating at the beginning of the journey only.  Space travel is currently done this way but only because our technology can't deliver sustained acceleration.  As plenty of others have mentioned, in your setting where acceleration is magically whatever we want it to be this trip would be done with constant acceleration throughout.  The side benefit of this would be not having to deal with microgravity for the duration of the journey.

Comment: @Cereza Uh, seems to me like you just need to get yourself a nice set of inertial dampeners XD

Comment: @JBH  Unfortunately, the question as currently worded asks "necessary to cross the distance between Jupiter and the sun" - which is implicitly straight-line.  It does not ask about actually *travelling* between the two, which is (as you say) a *far* more interesting question, at least in 1 direction (Sun-to-Jupiter.  The other direction is just falling with style...)

Comment: @Chronocidal, Forgive me, but I disagree.  I suspect if you spoke to the folks at NASA, they'd describe "crossing the distance between A and B" all the time, all the while understanding that there is *no celestial distance whatsoever that is crossed in a straight line.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic equation here is s=1/2 at^2, where s is distance, a is acceleration, and t is time. You have to allow for deceleration on the other end, so assuming you decelerate at the same rate that you accelerated, the easiest way to do the calculation is to cut the distance in half, then double everything when you're done.

Distance from the Sun to Jupiter is about 483 million miles. So if we want to make the whole trip in 30 days with a continuous, even acceleration, then we want to go half-way in 15 days, then decelerate for the next 15 days.

Halfway is 242 million miles. That's 1.28e12 feet. 15 days=1.30e6 seconds. So

```
s=1/2 a*t^2
1.28e12=1/2 * a * (1.30e6)^2
a=1.5
```

That's 1.5 ft/sec^-2, or about .04g. That's a pretty mild acceleration rate.

Answer (score 2):

Jupiter's aphelion (maximum distance between it and the sun) is 816040000km. When you're talking about rockets that aren't limited by energy, that's not really very far. That means you don't have to worry about relativistic effects (if you removed your 30-day constraint, even at 100G you wouldn't even reach a mere 10% of the speed of light before you hard to start slowing down).

So, given your 30 day constraint, an easy answer might be to boost up to cruising speed at 1G, and break at 1G, easy. A handy equation for this sort of trajectory is apparently $$T = \frac{D - A t^2}{A t} + 2t$$ where *T* is the total transit time, *D* is the distance travelled, *A* is the acceleration and *t* is the length of the acceleration or deceleration burn. You can rearrange this to a nice quadratic $Tt-t^2 - \frac{D}{A}= 0$ which you can solve to get a *t* of more or less 32500 seconds or a bit over **9 hours of thrust** at the start and end of your flight with 29-and-a-bit days of microgravity coasting in between. (disclaimer: I'm not taking into account planetary movement or effort required to leave/enter orbit as it is only a fairly small part of the problem, but you might do well to think about that, too)

An alternative (as Jay suggested first, though I'll use metric and latex so it must be better, right?) is to do a continuous acceleration-decceleration trajectory called a *brachistochrone* which is nicely defined by this equation:

$$ T = 2 \sqrt{ \frac{D}{A} } $$

which you can rearrange to $A = \frac{4D}{t^2}$ to get **a steady acceleration of about 0.49m/s** or **0.05G**. I won't go into the harm that extended periods of low-gravity exposure will cause you; that's a different question altogther. You should bear it in mind though, because in either of those two examples that's a long flight without much gravity to keep you in good working order.

---

**Reality check**: the continuous low thrust mode needs 1259km/s $\Delta_v$. With a mass ratio of 10, that needs an exhaust velocity of 547km/s. Good news: whilst this is too high for any sort of electrical rocket, a fusion-based rocket could manage this, so it isn't super implausible. Bad news: to provide the required acceleration, your ship needs a thrust power of something like 133kW per kilo fully loaded. This means that the aforementioned ship with a mass ratio of 10 needs a thrust power of 1.33MW per kilo, unfuelled. That in turn means that if its dry weight were 1000 tonnes, it needs a **1.3 terawatt** rocket. Nuclear engines being what they are, that figure will only get larger once you account for energy lost as heat and radiation (of which there will be a *colossal* amount). Not impossible, but, y'know, be aware of what "power is not a problem" can actually mean in practise.

If you do the 1G boost followed by a long coast, you actually only need a $\Delta_v$ of more like 638km/s and hence an exhaust velocity of 277km/s. Still sounds pretty nuclear, and the overall engine power is still pretty much the same.

In both cases, *the ship arrives dry*. If you want enough fuel for parking or a return trip, everything gets much, *much* harder.

---

Speaking of power not being a problem, why limit yourself to making the transit in 30 days?

A 1G brachistochrone takes about 160 hours (under a week). But wait! people can cope with over 1G for a little while. According to [this Space Exploration question](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/6530/29766), people can survive 1.5G for a week with no ill effects. That'll get you down to 130 hours (about 5 and a half days).

You could probably push that up a bit further, given a bit of endurance training and maybe some G-suits, so 2G will get you down to 113 hours (under 5 days). Beyond that you start running into serious physiological issues but also diminishing returns... a 4G continuous burn would get you there in 80 hours and a potentially survivable 10G only cuts that down to 50 hours. Take home message: squishy meat freight is squishy. If you're in a hurry, send a machine.

(reality check 2: you might manage a 1G brachistochrone with a fusion or antimatter engine 100 times more powerful than the one mentioned above. Anything much power powerful than that starts needing large quantities of antimatter)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your acceleration at 1g, 9.8m/s<sup>2</sup>, since anything more would become uncomfortable. The distance from the sun to Jupiter is 778.5 million km. you have to take into account deceleration also. So if you use the acceleration of 9.8m/s<sup>2</sup> over ~72 hours and a deceleration of ~72 hours, this would get you to almost 10 million km/h which would allow you to cruse at that speed for a few hours before you have to decelerate.

If you did not count the acceleration and deceleration times, it would take almost 78 hours at that speed to cross that distance. Unfortunately, my math is failing me to account for the time and distance you would cover during those periods.

A nice calculator to help you is [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/physics/velocity_a_t.php)

Comment: Your calculations are correct for non-relativistic speeds (speeds much smaller than that of light) but unfortunately this breaks down the faster you go and you must put more energy in.

Comment: It is less than 1% of the speed of light, so non relativistic equations are still pretty viable

Comment: The distance traveled to Jupiter varies with launch windows.  Does the 778.5 million km distance represent the shortest distance with a valid launch window (the actual shortest distance is 588 million km, but planets don't stand still...).  Or are you taking an average and drawing a straight line?  Even with constant acceleration, the total distance traveled might be a lot more than that (not that doubling the travel time to 6 days wouldn't be inconvenient!)

Comment: @LioElbammalf OP placed no constraint on energy expenditure. In fact, the questions opens with *"Assuming the power source for such acceleration places no limit on things"*.

Comment: @Whitecold so it is, doing it in my head I was thinking just under 10%, must have missed a power of ten off somewhere.

Comment: @JBH that is the average distance between Jupiter and the sun. Launch windows don't really apply as I'm not taking into account other orbiting objects.

Comment: @Lio the number I calculated is slightly less than 1% c. Relativistic effects are still minimal. If the traveler is willing to accelerate at 2g's for several days than it would be a factor, but if fairly sure the traveler would have significant health issues, such as labored breathing and blood flow issues

Comment: @Sonvar Ah-hah!  Frankly, I'd missed the statement about being between the sun and Jupiter (I assumed it was between the Earth and Jupiter).  However, a parabolic trajectory is still mandatory.  Straight-line space travel only works in fiction.

Comment: @JBH frankly I was just calculating for a straight line travel. Calculating a parabolic trajectory for such a case would be a waste of time